# Reference across files is followed by unwanted text

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I am writing an errata for a book. In this errata, I need to cross-refer to the pages where changes have taken place. I use the package `xr` to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{main}
\title{List of Changes}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
On page~\pageref{ch:intro}, I changed...
\end{document}
```

`ch:intro` is a label in my `main` document, which is located in the same directory. I expected to see the output

> On page 7, I changed...

But surprisingly, I saw

> On page 7Introductionchapter.1, I changed...

Where does the additional text "Introductionchapter.1" come from? Is it because of the style of `main`, the directory structure, the chapter structure, or the TeX engine? I tried some other labels and `\ref` instead of `\pageref`, but additional texts like this persisted.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you also make a MWE of your main document?

Comment: Are you chance using hyperref in your main document?

Comment: You should use hyperref in both documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error can be reproduces if the main document uses `hyperref`. If this is the case, use `xr-hyper` and `hyperref` also in the document, in which you want to import the labels.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{main}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{List of Changes}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
On page~\pageref{ch:intro}, I changed...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I have `hyperref` in the main document. I actually tried `xr-hyper` but didn't use `hyperref`. Using them together solves my problem.